# Access denied while downloading PDF using Python Requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am looking for downloading the PDFs with python and using `requests` library for the same. Following code works for some of the PDF documents but It throws an error for few documents.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import requests

filename = Path('c:/temp.pdf')
url = 'https://www.rolls-royce.com/~/media/Files/R/Rolls-Royce/documents/investors/annual-reports/rr-full%20annual%20report--tcm92-55530.pdf'
response = requests.get(url,verify=False)
filename.write_bytes(response.content)
```

Following is the exact response (`response.content`), however, I can download the same document using a chrome browser without any error

```
b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;rolls&#45;royce&#46;com&#47;&#37;7e&#47;media&#47;Files&#47;R&#47;Rolls&#45;Royce&#47;documents&#47;investors&#47;annual&#45;reports&#47;rr&#45;full&#37;20annual&#37;20report&#45;&#45;tcm92&#45;55530&#46;pdf" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;36ad4d68&#46;1562842755&#46;6294c42\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

Is there any way to get rid out of this?

Comment: have you tried setting `User-Agent` header?

Comment: No I did not try, can you help me out exactly what argument should be passed?

Comment: See the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You get `403 Forbidden` because `requests` by default sends `User-Agent: python-requests/2.19.1` header and server denies your request.

You can get the correct value for this header from your browser and everything will be fine.

For example:

```py
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 YaBrowser/19.6.1.153 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.rolls-royce.com/~/media/Files/R/Rolls-Royce/documents/investors/annual-reports/rr-full%20annual%20report--tcm92-55530.pdf'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)  # 200
```

Comment: status code received 200 but It does not download the PDF successfully. but when i am using headers={'User-Agent': 'My Browser'} then It downloads the PDF successfully.

Comment: However, I got another used case. I am not able to download the PDF for the link (https://www.eisai.com/ir/library/annual/pdf/epdf2017ir.pdf) even using the headers as mentioned earlier.